# Why isn’t this way of generating electricity well documented / not at all?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

After looking up different examples of inducing a voltage in a coil on Google and Youtube, I cannot find this being a known way of generating a voltage. In the image the brown arrow is the direction of the magnetic force and the green arrow is the direction of the velocity of the magnet. So the magnet moves from one end of the coil to the other while the polarity faces the coil directly.

[image]

What made this more interesting after doing test experiments with a friend is that you could have multiple magnets around the coils and generate a higher voltage as long as all the polarities facing the coil were the same. What ever the voltage of one magnet was times the amount of magnets inducing the coil was how you get the ending voltage.

[image]

I don’t understand why if this is a known way of generating a voltage that isn’t documented at all from my research. I doubt that this is a new discovery but still confused as to why I cannot find any evidence at all of this being a known thing. Can some one please help me out?

Comment: What is the difference between this and the conventional way of moving a coil in a magnetic field (or moving a magnetic field around a coil)?

Comment: In a way nothing it would generate the same amount of voltage as if the magnet were to go inside the coil like the conventional way. It the matter of I can not find this way anywhere I look I can only find the conventional way of inducing electricity in a coil. So if you know of a website or youtube video that shows this way can you please send it to me casue every where I look I can't find this way of inducing a voltage in a coil.

Comment: It is a known thing in the sense that a current is induced if a magnetic field and a conductor move relative to each other. But you can't find anything about doing that with this particular configuration probably because it's an inefficient configuration so no one bothers doing anything with it. It seems like there would be a lot of leakage and it doesn't lend itself well to rotary motion. Not to say you couldn't hook it up to a reciprocating/piston engine, thought the output would be very high frequency.

Comment: No matter at what angle you look at it, it is still a coil that experiences a moving magnetic field.

Comment: yeah, nothing about this is "not well documented" or "unknown". This is just an inefficient linear electrical machine. You don't need to know anything "special". The exact same equations describing what happens when you move a magnet inside the coil apply. You just need to apply them to this geometry.

Comment: The complete documentation of this is called ["Maxwell's equations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) and is very well known since about 150 years.

Comment: Make a circle out of it and you have something called a generator, so generic doesnt need any adjectives.  Not remotely new, my guess is every single web page you researched covered this.

Answer (score 1):

It's known, but FREAKIN' HARD TO CALCULATE.

So, in any textbooks, it's just that nobody uses it as homework problems.

It's "known," but not in low-level introductory materials.  You'll find the same situation with any simple physics with difficult math: supposedly "unknown," until you personally make the discovery, and start yer playin' widdit.

You need CAD numerical simulation to learn accurate results (or, just build the thing and see.)   I think Quickfield Student Edition might handle stuff like this.  Maybe.

PS

The magnet only induces a voltage while it's near the coil-ends.  When sliding along the coil center, it creates two opposed voltages.  When the magnet is against the coil and far from the ends (with a long coil,) the upstream and downstream voltages cancel out.   Same thing happens when shoving a short magnet into the center of a long coil:  it only generates energy as the magnet first enters the coil, or when the magnet is leaving the far end.

I think those AC flywheel flashlights use this circuit.  But they bend the coil into a ring, and put the bar magnet on a cup-shaped flywheel, then spin the flywheel.  It's a very Nikola Tesla design (like his original Gramme Ring, his AC 3ph motor, based on a shorted loop that's wound on a toroid iron core.)